# How to use rendered json data in React component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm rendering a page on get and passing a json object with it, like so:

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const message = req.session.message;
  res.render('index', { data: message });
});
```

This is my index.ejs view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='react-app'> Loading &hellip;</div>
  </body>
  <script src="/javascripts/build.js"></script>
</html>
```

The page that's being rendered is index.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './css/msha.scss';

import Store from './store';
import TemplateContainer from './components/TemplateContainer';

const renderApp = (Component) => {
  render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <Component />
      </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.querySelector('#react-app'),
  );
};

renderApp(TemplateContainer);

if (module && module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./components/TemplateContainer', () => {
    renderApp(TemplateContainer);
  });
}
```

The page being rendered contains a react component. How do I access this data inside the react component?

Comment: What template engine do you use? And show your `index` view code.

Comment: I just added my index.ejs.

Comment: I would say the easiest way would be to make an express route that returns the data as json, instead of trying to pass it through your rendering engine. then in your react app make an ajax call for it when it loads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of the ways is to add an object to the global scope and use it from the component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='react-app'> Loading &hellip;</div>
    <script>
      window.data = <%- JSON.stringify(data) %>;
    </script>
    <script src="/javascripts/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```